# What would you pejoratively call a illegitimate child who is born between one's own wife and an outsider (landlord) because of debt under duress?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

What word would English speaker come up with for a illegitimate child who is born between one's wife and an outsider (landlord) because of a debt /duress?

The word in Kannada language in India literally translates to "interest-son", this popular Kannada swear word is steeped in feudal traditions. Back in the days around the crusade times, when poor peasants did not have money to pay interest on the loans they borrowed from zamindars (Landlords), Under duress to pay debt they sent their wives as "financial interest" (usually long standing because of manipulation to take advantage) to the zamindar. The child born out of this interest (baddi) is thus called a baddi-maga in kannada

Comment: Different eras, cultures and customs have different expressions, so you're going to have to phrase your question in the past tense. Nowadays,  a woman giving birth to an illegitimate child, regardless of who the father is, carries much less stigma than say 60 or 120 years ago.

Comment: I checked the OED's historical thesaurus, and didn't find anything so I doubt a term meaning exactly that exists. There is, however, a very offensive word used to describe a male child of a prostitute (whoreson) which might be the closest you're going to get.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because English doesn't have words for things not experienced in English culture.

Comment: @AndyT English ***does*** have words for things not experienced in English culture, too.

Comment: Are there words in Kannada for other types of bastards? Those from a romance? Those from rape? Those from incest?

Comment: I am not a Kannada speaker in particular, but while in among kannadigas (Kannada natives) baddi-maga is a common expression.

Answer (score 4):

An old pejorative word for an illegitimate child is [**bastard**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bastard)

> a person born to parents who are not married to each other:
>
> - He was born in 1798, the bastard son of a country squire and his mistress.

The Online Etymology Dictionary says [**bastard**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bastard#etymonline_v_5301) (n.) "illegitimate child," originated in the

> early 13c., ***from Old French bastard "acknowledged child of a nobleman by a woman other than his wife"*** (11c., Modern French bâtard), probably from fils de bast "packsaddle son," meaning a child conceived on an improvised bed (saddles often doubled as beds while traveling), with pejorative ending -art (see -ard). Alternative possibly is that the word is from Proto-Germanic *banstiz "barn," equally suggestive of low origin. Compare German bänkling "bastard; child begotten on a bench" (and not in a marriage bed), the source of English bantling (1590s) "brat, small child." Bastard was not always regarded as a stigma; the Conqueror is referred to in state documents as "William the Bastard." Figurative sense of "something not pure or genuine" is late 14c. Use as a generic vulgar term of abuse for a man is attested from 1830. Among the "bastard" words in Halliwell-Phillipps' "Dictionary of Archaic and Provincial Words" are avetrol, chance-bairn, by-blow, harecoppe, horcop, and gimbo ("a bastard's bastard"). As an adjective from late 14c. It is used of things spurious or not genuine, having the appearance of being genuine, of abnormal or irregular shape or size, and of mongrels or mixed breeds.

A blog post about [**medieval bastards**](http://cdalebrittain.blogspot.com/2015/06/medieval-bastards.html) from Life in the Middle Ages by a professor of medieval history, C Dale Brittain says

> ***There were at least four different categories of illegitimate children in medieval law.***  **A manzer**, a term with Hebrew roots, was a child born to a prostitute or sometimes to an incestuous union, that is **a child whose parents' relationship was considered morally wrong**.  **A nothus**, a word with Greek roots, was **the child of a married woman due to an adulterous affair**, also morally wrong.  **A spurius** was **the child of** a couple who could not have been married, such as a citizen and a non-citizen (in those cities that regulated who citizens could marry), or **a well-born man and a slave in late antiquity, or a married man and a concubine**.  **A naturalis** was the offspring of a couple who could have married and indeed might do so in the future; this last category was treated fairly indulgently, **the product of "young love" that got carried away.**
>
> **In spite of medieval lawyers' efforts to create clear categories, the exact definitions of these four terms was fairly fluid**.  A chronicler might decide to call the son of a lord and his concubine a manzer rather than a spurius if he disliked the son.  Someone showing off his Greek might call any child of an unmarried couple a nothus.  Whether the mother or the father was the highborn adulterer, some chroniclers would use nothus, some spurius.  **By the twelfth century, the words illegitimus and bastardus were also in common use, meaning any child whose birth seemed somewhat irregular.**

Another blog post entitled [**Killing Buddy McKay**](https://strangebehaviors.wordpress.com/2016/03/04/killing-buddy-mackay/) on strange behaviors - Cool doings from the natural and human worlds, **quotes Ullas Karanth, director of the Wildlife Conservation Society in India** as saying.

> “I kept seeing this guy’s tracks and **saying ‘Baddi maga! Baddi maga! Baddi maga!’” It’s a local curse, best translated simply as “Bastard!”**  (But worse: At one time, a debtor who fell behind on his interest payments could be obliged to surrender his wife to the lender for a time.  Any resulting child was the “baddi maga,” or “interest child.”)

The same information is published on takepart.com in an article entitled [**The Death of a Leopard Named Buddy MacKay**](http://www.takepart.com/article/2016/03/04/death-leopard-named-buddy-mackay) ("Buddy McKay" being a play on words - Baddi Maga)

The [**Times of India**](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/articleshow/46262500.cms?utm_source=contentofinterest&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=cppst) reported, on February 16, 2015, that **the**

> **word led to a huge discussion recently.** T**he word, 'baddimaga' is being commonly used in films. It originates from 'boddimaga' which is a vulgar usage meaning bastard.** However, in recent colloquial usage it has morphed into 'baddimaga' and taken on different meanings. Since 'baddi' means loan interest in Kannada, baddimaga took the of a person who cheats.

It's unlikely that there is a specific word in English referring to an illegitimate child who is born between one's wife and an outsider (landlord) because of a debt /duress.